# How to open phonebook from android application?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am working on android app in which I want to open phonebook on button click event. Will I have to use intent for that?

Thanks,
Vishakha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
```

To get more into this see [Android – Open Contacts Activity and Return Chosen Contact](http://eclipsed4utoo.com/blog/android-open-contacts-activity-return-chosen-contact/)

Comment: it was really useful can you tell me can i add a contact in same application if yes how

Comment: check this out: http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/App/weightapp/org/nextive/android/weightapp/AddContact.java.htm